# Maven gives this project has disliked artifacts error when using Jung dependency

Tags: maven, jung

I have a Java project where I want to make some calls to a Jung library. I added the following lines to the pom.xml 
    
        net.sf.jung
        jung-algorithms
        2.0.1

However when I run "mvn package", I get the following error
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal licensing-maven-plugin:1.
7.5:check (enforce-licensing-oss) on project server-examples: This project
 has 3 disliked artifacts. -> [Help 1]

Any insights as to what may be going wrong ?

Comment: The lines that I added to the maven file are

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-algorithms</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have configured the licensing-maven-plugin to complain when you introduce a dependency with certain licenses. You, or whoever wrote your pom. If you read the configuration for that plugin it will tell you what licenses it is configured to like and dislike.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this dependency for a specific run without re-installing maven

Comment: It has nothing to do with Maven. It is a plugin _you_ control in _your_ pom. You can delete the licensing-maven-plugin altogether if you no longer want it.

Comment: Thanks. It was clearly a license check issue.
The pom.xml that I was using was using a parent pom. This parent pom was incorporating automatic license checks for all included artifacts to ensure license compliance.
Just getting rid of the parent pom by commenting out the <parent> tag worked as it disabled the license compliance checks.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25410761/adding-jung-dependencies-to-neo4j-server-plugin-extensions